# Video Pop Up on HTML close button missing. How can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, html

`<a class="js__popup" href="#" title="Intro Video"> <i class="s-icon s-icon--lg s-icon--white-bg g-radius--circle ti-control-play"></i>`

when i click video button i cant close it, how to add close button